# Azure AKS Redis deployments

Tags: kubernetes, azure-devops, redis, azure-aks

I want to make a Redis instance for my namespaces. I use Azure AKS.I have default, dev, qa and stg namespaces.I already have deployed the Redis in default namespace but after that is impossible to make this for others.Then I tried to make another one namespace ( redis ) but the result was the same , it is still  pending.

> PS D:\Code\Infrastructure> kubectl -n redis  get pods
> NAME         READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
> redis-0      0/1     Pending   0          34s
> sentinel-0   0/1     Pending   0          12s

[image]

Here are the link to resources that I use: [GITHUB](https://github.com/marcel-dempers/docker-development-youtube-series/tree/master/storage/redis/kubernetes)

Comment: Did you try deleting these existing PVC and re-deploy the deployment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted all existing pvc and after that I was created new storage class with name development then I referred storageClassName: development